# Multiple popup modal opens at same time instead of single popup in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

call API using fetch and get a response in the console and assign values to the table header. after that create one button in react js. Each button has one video URL which is got from the API response

```
API response:

Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/0"

Group_Name: "Group_2"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/1"
```

Then use the map function to pass the video name as the source for a popup video player.
after that, I click on the button but I open up multiple video popups at the same time.  But I want it so that only that certain video that was clicked would show.

I tried this code:

```
export default function App(data, handleFormSubmit) {
  const { id } = data;
  const actionButton = (params) => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const [videoName, setvideoName] = useState();
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialValue);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setFormData(initialValue);
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { value, id } = e.target;
    // console.log(value,id)
    setFormData({ ...formData, [id]: value });
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Name", field: "Company_Name", filter: "agSetColumnFilter" },
    { headerName: "Floor", field: "Floor Number" },
    { headerName: "Group", field: "Group_Name" },
    { headerName: "Camera", field: "Camera_Number" },
    { headerName: "Videos", field: "Video_Name" },
    {
      headerName: "Actions",
      field: "Video_Name",
      cellRendererFramework: (params) => (
        <div>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            size="medium"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => actionButton(params)}
          >
            Play
          </Button>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  const defaultColDef = {
    sortable: true,
    flex: 1,
    filter: true,
    floatingFilter: true,
    groupDisplayType: "groupRows",
    animateRows: true,
  };

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    console.log("grid is ready");
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/get_all")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.results);
        setResponse(resp.results);
        params.api.applyTransaction({ add: resp.results });
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 align="center"> React FastAPI Integration</h1>
      <h3> API Data </h3>
      <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "400px" }}>
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
          pagination={true}
        ></AgGridReact>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <DialogContent>
            {response.map(({ Video_Name }) => (
              <iframe
                width="420"
                height="315"
                title="videos"
                src={Video_Name}
              />
            ))}
          </DialogContent>
        
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How to resolve this using reactjs

Thanks